# While working with Selenium WebDriver and Java I am not able to use click() function of WebDriver (giving no exception)

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I have set the following properties:-

1. Set environment variables JAVA_HOME,path,ANT_HOME,path (using JDK version --> jdk1.7.0_40)
2. In Eclipse set the system Library, added all needed jars and select all jars in Order and Export.
3. Install the Firefox Version 24 and used the Selenium jar(selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0).
4. Giving no error while running the Java application, also no exception while not able to click on particular element.
5. sendKeys(Keys.ENTER) is working fine, but instead I need to use click() method.

Also code is working fine on other systems, I think I am missing something.
click() method is not giving any valid response, it makes me feel like its only declared not defined. I have tried on different websites, on different elements and with different types(xpath, css selector, name, id) but nothing worked for me. I took focus on that element by webdriver and also by highlighting the element using javascript code, its showing that particular element is present. I have performed other operations like entering username after clicking on that element, its performing well. I have worked with different browsers, different webpages also maximize the window using selenium but no positive response.

Any help will appreciate.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please post the code here?

Comment: public static void main(String[] s)
 {
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("https://web210.qa.drfirst.com/login.jsp");
  driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).click();
 }

Comment: note:- Code is working in other Pc's

Comment: What does "not able to click on particular element" mean? Does the `click()` method block? Does it click somewhere else? Does it not do anything at all (how do you know?) and just passes? Does it work on different webpages? Does it work in a different browser? Do you have any zoom level set in Firefox?

Comment: @Slanec:- I have updated the description part.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the snippet below worked fine for me

```
  public static void main(String[]args){


    WebDriver appDriver;

    appDriver = new FirefoxDriver();

    appDriver.get("https://web210.qa.drfirst.com/login.jsp");

    WebElement loginButton = appDriver.findElement(By.className("btn"));

    loginButton.click();

    appDriver.switchTo().alert().accept();

    appDriver.close();
}
```

Comment: I have mentioned its working on other PC's, its not working only on my PC, I think some step is missing I am looking for that miss.